# Tag for Macbook Pros with retina displays?

Tags: discussion, tags

What is the tag for Macbook Pros with retina displays?

In this case, I created [retina-display](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/retina-display).  Any better ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the tag is too specific, or just untimely. Perhaps we should wait for a relevant *non-hypothetical* question before creating the tag, e.g. what problems Ubuntu is having on someone's Macbook that are related to the retina display -- specifically, the *retina* part?

In general, I think [resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/resolution) is a good fit for now.